# Metro UI  apps in Windows 8 does not work after joining to domain in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-8

I have installed Windows 8 recently and I created a Live account. Before joining to my domain, all apps in Metro UI works fine (Mail, Calendar, People, SkyDrive, ...).

After joining to domain, they are not working.

When I log in with my local user, the apps are working. But with my domain account login, they are not working (when I click them, nothing happens and the apps do not run).

Edited: it seems that it is an issue and there are many people with the same problem.

Comment: @HopelessN00b "not working" means when you click it, nothing happens!

Comment: My guess is its because calendar, etc are linked to your Live account, but when you log in as a domain user there are probably things that are incompatible. I havent linked my live account to my domain joined Windows 8 machine, and as a result it prompts me for my live account every time I attempt to access those apps

Comment: @MarkHenderson Exactly true, I tested without linking Live account and the apps are working now.

Comment: Ask Microsoft support.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is its because calendar, etc are linked to your Live account, but when you log in as a domain user there are probably things that are incompatible.

I haven't linked my live account to my domain joined Windows 8 machine, and as a result it prompts me for my live account every time I attempt to access those apps.

Try un-linking your Live account and see how that goes. I suspect this probably is a bug or something un-documented.

Comment: Unfortunately, as soon as I entered my Live account data in Mail application, it's closed! I checked that my Live account is not linked.